# CL VIM: How to get 256 color support in Fedora 17 terminal?

Tags: bash, vim, fedora

How do I enable 256 color support for VIM in the Fedora 17 terminal?

My .bashrc:

```
1 # .bashrc
2 
3 # Makes terminal default 256 Colors Include these lines in .bashrc
4 
5 export TERM=xterm-256color
6 
7 # User specific aliases and functions
8 
9 alias rm='rm -i'
10 alias cp='cp -i'
11 alias mv='mv -i'
12 
13 # Source global definitions
14 if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
15         . /etc/bashrc
16 fi
17
```

Tput colors return 8, I am using 256 jellybeans for vim color, it changes some of the colors, but does not nearly work as shown in the screenshot (due to the fact the terminal only supports 8 colors)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The TERM environment variable is only informative. It tells Apps what terminal you are currently using. It doesn't change the behaviour of the terminal. The terminal sets it to what it should be. You don't usually change it. Just make sure you are using a terminal with 256 color support first.

Comment: This belongs on SuperUser or Unix & Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is from [Fedora Project site](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/256_Color_Terminals):

```
local256="$COLORTERM$XTERM_VERSION$ROXTERM_ID$KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION"

if [ -n "$local256" ] || [ -n "$SEND_256_COLORS_TO_REMOTE" ]; then

  case "$TERM" in
    'xterm') TERM=xterm-256color;;
    'screen') TERM=screen-256color;;
    'Eterm') TERM=Eterm-256color;;
  esac
  export TERM

  if [ -n "$TERMCAP" ] && [ "$TERM" = "screen-256color" ]; then
    TERMCAP=$(echo "$TERMCAP" | sed -e 's/Co#8/Co#256/g')
    export TERMCAP
  fi
fi

unset local256
```

To test:

```
tput colors
```

Output should be `256`

Answer (score 0):

I have this line in my `.vimrc` file:

```
set t_Co=256
```

Here is some additional information as well: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim